# Bind Command to a ComboBoxItem in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, binding, command

I have a wpf project with a `ComboBox`. The items there inside are filled in dynamically. So it is bound to a model which contains a `Label` and a Command.

If the User selects an item in the Dropdown / `ComboBox` the Command should be executed. I tried it with a `DataTemplate` containing a `TextBlock` and a `Hyperlink` for the Command. But the Command will only execute if a select the `Label` (`Hyperlink`) and not if I click on the whole item.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=States}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentState}" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Hyperlink Command="{Binding Command}" TextDecorations="None" Foreground="Black">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Label}"/>
                </Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

So the question is now, how can I bind my Command to a `ComboBoxItem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ComboBoxItem` has no `Command` property but you could execute the command from the setter of the `CurrentState` property:

```
private State _currentState;
public State CurrentState
{
    get { return _currentState; }
    set
    {
        _currentState = value;
        if (_currentState != null)
        {
            _currentState.Command.Execute(null);
        }
    }
}
```

This property will be set whenever you select an item in the `ComboBox`. The other option would be to handle the `SelectionChanged` event in the view.